# C/C++ char **argv VS *argv[]

Tags: c++, c

Please I have been wondering, what's the difference between char **argv and char *argv[] in the main function of the C/C++ main function. Please I will appreciate any answer, thanks.

Comment: Did you mean `char** argv` and not `char** argv[]`? Because that's the correct form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you mean `char **argv` and `char *argv[]`, then both are the same. Array declarations in function parameters are decayed to their pointer type, so it is just a matter of preference which one you use.

Comment: Thank you for your contributions.

Comment: So if I choose to use char ** argv[] instead of the default char *argv[] it will not affect my code ?

Comment: @user3526881: If is either `char **argv` (no square brackets and two `*`) **or** `char *argv[]` (square brackets and one `*`). And you can use either one, it will not make a difference. However `char **argv[]` (square brackets and two `*`) is not correct.

Comment: @user3526881 There's nothing valid like `char ** argv[]`, it's `char* argv[]` or `char ** argv`, period!

Comment: @user3526881 Also note that when we say they are interchangeable, we mean they are interchangeable as *function parameters*. When you are creating an object of type `T* x[n]`,  that is actually creating an array of `n` pointers. Arrays *decay* to pointers when passing them as arguments.